# CassandraOperations ingest not writing complete list

Tags: java, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to build high speed insert/delete in a cassandra database but a fourth of the data is not getting inserted.

When using Spring Repository.save(List) everything is good (but catastrophic in terms of CPU usage) so I tried the provided CassandraOperations.ingest() (or CQLOperations.ingest()). When dealing with small amount of data everything goes fine, but when I get to several hundreds of records, I start losing data.

Here is an extract of the insert code:

```
private final String insertPreparedCql = "insert into keyspace.MyData (s, f, m, b, av, c, AD, ga, an, ti, tim, pre, pre2, de, ch, cha, sig, rs, abc, frO, sub, sub1, en, eni, prod, gde, gude, gpde, gpd, gat, gong, glt) "
        + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    List<List<?>> llData = new ArrayList<>();

    while(!lbufferedData.isEmpty()){

        LNSData dat = lbufferedData.remove(0);
        List<Object> lUniqData = new ArrayList<>();

        lUniqData.add(dat.getS());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getF());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getM());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getB));
        lUniqData.add(dat.getAv());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getC());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getAD());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGa());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getAn());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getTi());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getTim());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getPre());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getPre2());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getDe());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getCl());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getCSI());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getSSI());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getRev());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getABC());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getFet());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getSus());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getSus1());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getEe());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getEni());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getPId());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGude());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGde());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGpde());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGid());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGLat());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGng());
        lUniqData.add(dat.getGt());

        llData.add(lUniqData);

    }
    if(llData.size()>0){
        logger.debug("Inserting {} elements processed data", llData.size());
        cassandraTemplate.ingest(insertPreparedCql, llData);
    }
```

When using 'watch -n 1 nodetool tpstats' I noticed the Native-Transport-Requests had All time blocked values, so I set the option -Dcassandra.max_queued_native_transport_requests=4096. No more blocked elements (or dropped), but still everything is not written properly.

I tried calling the ingest only once with all the elements, or multiple time in smaller batches, but the result is always the same (with various amount of lost data).

Same goes with a delete which is based on the PRIMAY KEY elements.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't use the `ingest` method. It discards any response (success, failures). Please use either `executeAsynchronously(…)` or `session.executeAsync(…)` and keep track of the asynchronous responses.

Comment: Agreed on the pb of not being able to keep track of the inserts. I ended up reimplementing the ingest methods and keeping track of the preparedStatement in a HashMap to avoid recreating them at each request. Used also sess.execute and executeAsync both seems to be working correctly. So it looks like the creation of a similar preparedStatement in the same session cancelled the previous request.