# Losing data on bulk inserts in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm in trouble for losing data on insert in my Cassandra.

I am doing great bulk inserts from csv files which I read via Stream. The data is duplicated into two tables, because of different queries. Every 30,000th element I split my data to new partition (chunkCounter).

```
 private PersistenceInformation persist(final String period, final String tradePartner, final Integer version, Stream<Transaction> transactions) {

    int elementsInChunkCounter = 0;
    int chunkCounter = 1;
    int elementCounter = 0;

    Iterator<Transaction> iterator = transactions.filter(beanValidator).iterator();

    List<List<?>> listImportData = new ArrayList<>(30000);
    List<List<?>> listGtins = new ArrayList<>(30000);

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Transaction tr = iterator.next();

        List<Object> importTemp = new ArrayList<>(9);
        importTemp.add(period);
        importTemp.add(tradePartner);
        importTemp.add(version);
        importTemp.add(chunkCounter);
        importTemp.add(tr.getMdhId());
        importTemp.add(tr.getGtin());
        importTemp.add(tr.getQuantity());
        importTemp.add(tr.getTransactionId());
        importTemp.add(tr.getTimestamp());
        listImportData.add(importTemp);

        List<Object> gtinTemp = new ArrayList<>(8);
        gtinTemp.add(period);
        gtinTemp.add(tradePartner);
        gtinTemp.add(version);
        gtinTemp.add(chunkCounter);
        gtinTemp.add(tr.getMdhId());
        gtinTemp.add(tr.getGtin());
        gtinTemp.add(tr.getQuantity());
        gtinTemp.add(tr.getTimestamp());
        listGtins.add(gtinTemp);

        elementsInChunkCounter++;
        elementCounter++;

        if (elementsInChunkCounter == 30000) {
            elementsInChunkCounter = 0;
            chunkCounter++;

            ingestImportData(listImportData);
            listImportData.clear();

            ingestGtins(listGtins);
            listGtins.clear();
        }
    }

    if (!listImportData.isEmpty()) {
        ingestImportData(listImportData);
    }

    if (!listGtins.isEmpty()) {
        ingestGtins(listGtins);
    }

    return new PersistenceInformation();
}

private void ingestImportData(List<List<?>> list) {
    String cqlIngest = "INSERT INTO import_data (pd, tp , ver, chunk, mdh_id, gtin, qty, id, ts) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    cassandraOperations.ingest(cqlIngest, list);
}

private void ingestGtins(List<List<?>> list) {
    String cqlIngest = "INSERT INTO gtins (pd, tp, ver, chunk, mdh_id, gtin, qty, ts) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    cassandraOperations.ingest(cqlIngest, list);
 }
```

This worked pretty well until I noticed that sometimes a dataset goes missing. There is an entry in the second table (gtins) but the data set in the main table was not inserted. The application counted it but the database did not write it.

The table is built this way:

```
CREATE TABLE import_data (
    tp text,
    pd text,  
    ver int,
    chunk int,
    mdh_id uuid,
    gtin text,
    qty float,
    id text,
    ts timestamp
PRIMARY KEY ((tp, pd, ver, chunk), ts, mdh_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);
```

The mdh_id is a UUID from my application, so that every data set has a unique key and is not accidentally overridden.

The Cassandra log files didn't even show a warning.

At the moment I am evaluating BatchStatement but I need to insert every 8th dataset because of the 5kb limit, otherwise the database lost even more entries.

Any suggestions whats going wrong in my application is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652387/cassandraoperations-ingest-not-writing-complete-list. Don't use `ingest`. It's doing fire&forget of `INSERT` statements. Either use the synchronous `insert` or run asynchronous queries yourself where you keep track of the created futures and handle exceptions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Sorry for the duplicate.